# Instantiate Parameterized Type class with Class<?> variable

Tags: java, generics, parameterized-types

Consider if I have a class or enum `Foo` where each instance has a `Class<?> type` field:

```
public enum Foo {
    A (Integer.class), B (Double.class), C (String.class);

    public final Class<?> type;

    Foo(Class<?> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Then I have a generic class `Bar<V>`:

```
public class Bar<V> {

    private V value;

    // default constructor
    public Bar() {}

    // getter
    public V getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    // setter
    public void setValue(V value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to instantiate an instance of `Bar` with the type from the `Class<?> type` field of a given `Foo` without knowing the specific type of `Foo.type`?  For instance, I would call this in either a static method, or some kind of factory method.

*Edit:*

To specify the function of Bar:  Bar wraps around a value with a simple getter/setter, and has a consistent interface, but an unknown type.  The benefit of my idea would be to create instances of Bar based off of an instance of Foo.  For instance, use value of `Foo.A.type` (which is `Integer.class`) to instantiate a `Bar<Integer>` without knowing ahead of time that `Foo.A.type` has a value of `Integer.class`.

Answer (score 1):

Given the constructor in the `Bar` class, in order to instantiate a new `Bar<V>` object, you need an object of type `V`.

So, your problem translates into instantiating an object of type `Class<V>`. More specifically, assuming an existing `Foo` object and a `getType()` method in the `Foo` class, you would do something like:

```
Foo foo = ... // Existing Foo object
Class<V> type = foo.getType();
V value = instantiate(type); // TODO: Implement instatiate()
Bar<V> bar = new Bar(value);
```

The trick then is the implementation of the `instantiate()` method. If `Class<V>` has a no-args constructor, then you can just call

```
V value = type.newInstance();
```

Not all classes have a default constructor, though, so there is no generic solution for all cases.

Comment: The problem is just that `type` in `Foo` is declared as `Class<?>` and therefore requires a cast to `Class<V>` which brings up a warning due to unchecked casting. Next, you should also add a diamond operator to the instantiation of `new Bar<>(value)`. You can also refactor the casting to the enum itself like `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") public <V> Class<V> getType() { return (Class<V>)type; }` and then just use somthing like `Class<String> type = Foo.C.getType();` but the compiler will also accept `Class<String> type = Foo.B.getType();` and then fail on runtime.

Comment: I apologize, my constructor example was misleading.  The point isn't to initialize the value, but to create a new instance of Bar without explicitly knowing the type and instead using the type from Foo.  I have edited my example.

Comment: You need to be more specific about the usage of V, then. Is it a return value of any of the methods of the Bar class? Is it the type of any of its variables?

Comment: I wrote more explanation of the usage of `V`.  `Bar` is a wrapper class, the point is to use instances of `Foo` to instantiate `Bar<V>` where `V` is the same class as `Foo.A.type` or `Foo.B.type`, etc.  Also, to do this without hardcoding in the class. (i.e., I don't know the type of `Foo.A` beforehand, but I know what it is via the `type` field.

Comment: Instead of just doing `Bar<Integer> = new Bar<>();`, I want to somehow pass the class referenced by a `type` field of an instance of `Foo` to the Bar I create.

Comment: @AaronCarson if in a factory type pattern, the calling code will be passing a concrete `type` (either of `Integer`, `Double` or `String`)? Right? If so then to me it sounds like you may need to write yet another piece of code which compares the passed type (from the factory client) with the enum types in `Foo`.

Comment: @user3320018 Are you suggesting something like a switch case on`type` where I explicitly state each type (that feels convoluted to me)? I can't figure out an elegant solution.

Comment: @AaronCarson I agree and I want to say that I keep hitting the wall when I think that client code is to provide one of the **concrete type** and then we want to use an (apparently?) **known type** from `Foo` to wrap it into a `Bar` instance.

Comment: I sm trying to design a factory method where I can pass in a `Foo` and get a `Bar` (Foo may have additional data associated).  `Foo` will also be used as a key in a map.